# Too much time in zone 5?

Tags: exercise, cardio, bicycling, overtraining, zone

In my most recent studio spin class, I spent around 20 minutes out of 40 in Zone 5, and most of the rest in zone 4. The occasion before that I was in zone 5 for 23 mins out of 55, zone 4 for 17 and zone 3 for the rest.

Am I exercising too hard?

I'm 37. Generally active in my leisure time (2 spins a week, occasional long distance hikes or bike rides at weekends) but I work a sedentary job and I don't have the best of diets.

I love the feeling of reaching my limit in a spin class, but have recently began to wonder if I'm doing too much.

I don't "feel" like I am, but I'm no expert here.

Answer (score 1):

**You *are* the expert of your body.**

How you feel is all that matters really. Consequences of overtraining are CNS fatique, prolonged muscle soreness (not starting to diminish 3 days post-workout), injuries and most likely a plateau or even decrease in performance.

> I love the feeling of reaching my limit in a spin class, but have recently began to wonder if I'm doing too much.
>
> I don't "feel" like I am, but I'm no expert here.

If, as you stated yourself, you're feeling good, you're not feeling overly tired or experiencing prolonged muscle soreness and you're seeing progress, then it's unlikely you're doing too much (overtraining).